# what is the mistake of convergence proof in Adam

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, optimization, adam

Sashank J. Reddi et. al in their paper "On the convergence of Adam and beyond" say that, Adam's proof of convergence as stated in original paper is wrong. More than that, they point out that the value

$Г_{t + 1} = \frac{\sqrt{V_{t+1}}}{a_{t+1}} - \frac{\sqrt{V_t}}{a_t}$,
where $V$ is moving average of squared gradients and $a$ is learning rate,

is presumed to be positive, however, it's only true for SGD and AdaGrad, while for RMSProp and Adam can be anything. I can't find a place where this property would be presumed and used in adam's origin convergence proof, can someone point it out to me ?

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is covered in David Martínez-Rubio's MSc thesis
https://damaru2.github.io/convergence_analysis_hypergradient_descent/dissertation_hypergradients.pdf
see pages 18 & 19 of thesis, where he points out it is used in theorem 10.5 of Kingma & Ba's paper,at bottom of page 14.

[image: page 18]

[image: page 19]

Comment: I think it would be better to quote the contents you are referring to directly in your answer. There is a non-negligible chance that the link you provided will break at any time, rendering your answer useless to future readers.

Comment: now added images of the proof